# Moment timezone changes to local after I set it

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I have a moment javascript code using timezones, and I'm trying to calculate a date relative to America/Chicago no matter where it is loaded. Then later I am showing a timespan that happens in America/Chicago relative to the user's local timezone.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdvy9za7

```
var d = moment("18:00", "HH:mm").tz("America/Chicago");
```

Line 31 is where I'm trying to set the date to be relative to America/Chicago. It doesn't matter what the date is what matters is that the time is 18:00. Later in the code Line 36 is where I get today's date to do a check on line 38

I'm trying to get the variable datenum to show the date number of today relative to America/Chicago no matter where the script is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert from a moment to a Javascript Date using `toDate()`, you are losing the timezone information and creating a Date based on the timestamp of the original moment, so you'll get a Date corresponding to 18:00 in the local timezone. See more thorough explanation in [this Github issue](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/309):

> The Date object has no time zone abilities other than working with the
>   local time zone. We can't do anything about that. When you use toDate,
>   any of moment or moment-timezone's ability to "represent" other time
>   zones is stripped away. You're left with the raw instant in time
>   represented by the timestamp [...]
>
> You might as well have just done moment(1493092800000).toDate() or
>   moment.utc(1493092800000).toDate(). It's all the same as just new
>   Date(1493092800000).

You can instead keep the moment and use Moment's `date()` method:

```
var d = moment("18:00", "HH:mm").tz("America/Chicago");
var datenum = d.date();
```

This will tell you what is the date locally, when it is 18:00 in Chicago.